# jQuery fadeOut triggering problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fadeout

Hey guys,
I'm using some **jQuery UI** to show and image by scaling and fading it in at the same time!

jquery.ui.core.js

jquery.effects.scale.js

```
$('img').show( "puff", 1000, function(){$(this).stop();} );
```

I've modified the plug-in so the scaling reaches 200% and at that moment I stop the animation so that it keeps the double size.
From here on my wish is to `fadeOut()` the image in that 2X state however I can't trigger fading effect.

```
$('img').show( "puff", 1000, function(){$(this).stop().fadeOut();} );
```

does not work and neither

```
$('img').show( "puff", 1000, function(){$(this).stop()} ).fadeOut();
```

anybody with a solution?

10x and BR

Comment: fadeOut is in the callback function. so it will only triggerr when show() is over

Comment: Yes indeed and stop() either but it worked, is there a way to reach the desirable effect ?

Answer (score 1):

use this in your call back

```
// set the value to 200%
$(this).css('some_property','200%');
$(this).fadeOut();
```

This way your stop doesn't need to be called

and at the end of the animation, the size will be set to 200% then starts fading out